# UITapGestureRecognizer action not triggered

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an UIImageView inside a subclass of UITableViewCell in which I wired up with UITapGestureRecognizer. However, when I press on the image the action is not triggered. What's being triggered is the didSelectRowAtIndexPath.. why is this?

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)];
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1; 
tapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1; 
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture]; [tapGesture release];
```

Also one minor question is that I have a UITextView in the cell, however when I click on the text it did not trigger the didSelectRowAtIndexPath, why is this and how do I change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIImageView has userInteractionEnabled set to NO by default. Try setting it to YES

```
imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

For your other question, try setting the editable property to NO for the UITextView.

```
textView.editable = NO;
```

Comment: okay, this is correct... I added another minor question related to this

Comment: If it does work for you, could you mark it as the correct answer?